# Zip mutiple folders and its contents VBA

Tags: vba, zip, directory

I have mutiple folders (appox. 400 and could increase up in some cases) and each of these folders contains some files. I wanted to zip all these folders with their contents and create 400 zip files. I wanted to automate this with VBA. I tried with the following code. The standard one which uses shell application.

```
Sub Zip_All_Files_in_Folder_Browse()
Dim FileNameZip, FolderName, oFolder
Dim strDate As String, DefPath As String
Dim oApp As Object

DefPath = Application.DefaultFilePath
If Right(DefPath, 1) <> "\" Then
    DefPath = DefPath & "\"
End If

strDate = Format(Now, " dd-mmm-yy h-mm-ss")
FileNameZip = DefPath & "MyFilesZip " & strDate & ".zip"

Set oApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

'Browse to the folder
Set oFolder = oApp.BrowseForFolder(0, "Select folder to Zip", 512)
If Not oFolder Is Nothing Then
    'Create empty Zip File
    NewZip (FileNameZip)

    FolderName = oFolder.Self.Path
    If Right(FolderName, 1) <> "\" Then
        FolderName = FolderName & "\"
    End If

    'Copy the files to the compressed folder
    oApp.Namespace(FileNameZip).CopyHere oApp.Namespace(FolderName).Items

        'Keep script waiting until Compressing is done
        On Error Resume Next
        Do Until oApp.Namespace(FileNameZip).Items.Count = _
        oApp.Namespace(FolderName).Items.Count
            Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
        Loop
        On Error GoTo 0

        MsgBox "You find the zipfile here: " & FileNameZip

    End If
End Sub

Sub NewZip(sPath)
'Create empty Zip File
    If Len(Dir(sPath)) > 0 Then Kill sPath
    Open sPath For Output As #1
    Print #1, Chr$(80) & Chr$(75) & Chr$(5) & Chr$(6) & String(18, 0)
    Close #1
End Sub
```

I can call the above code in loop to create mutiple zip folders. However, I was wondering if this is really an effcient process! Is there any alternative for this procedure? Sometimes my count of folders to be zipped may go beyound 1000. So I would really appreciate your suggestions and ideas on this.

Thank you in advance

Comment: if your code works without any errors, then submit here for hints on improving it https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Your code seems to work for you, so you seem to be looking for code review. [https://codereview.stackexchange.com/](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

A hint would be to use something other than Excel for this procedure. You are now relying on Excel for your code to work and that is not so great. A VBScript could work in your situation, that would unfortunately mean that you have to rewrite some parts of your code, and it's a bit different from excel's VBA. The best solution would be to use VB.NET in something like Visual Studio. It would mean that you have to rewrite some parts though.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I haven't checked yet the above code in loop. However I was assuming that it would work. I don't know much about VB.NET so you think the solution with VBA Excel would be cumbersome?

Comment: You could shell to to a command line zip utility.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you don't need everything separated into 400 different folders, you can combine them all into one zipped folder.

```
Sub Zip_All_Files_in_Folder_Browse()
    Dim FileNameZip, FolderName, oFolder
    Dim strDate As String, DefPath As String
    Dim oApp As Object

    DefPath = Application.DefaultFilePath
    If Right(DefPath, 1) <> "\" Then
        DefPath = DefPath & "\"
    End If

    strDate = Format(Now, " dd-mmm-yy h-mm-ss")
    FileNameZip = DefPath & "MyFilesZip " & strDate & ".zip"

    Set oApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

    'Browse to the folder
    Set oFolder = oApp.BrowseForFolder(0, "Select folder to Zip", 512)
    If Not oFolder Is Nothing Then
        'Create empty Zip File
        NewZip (FileNameZip)

        FolderName = oFolder.Self.Path
        If Right(FolderName, 1) <> "\" Then
            FolderName = FolderName & "\"
        End If

        'Copy the files to the compressed folder
        oApp.Namespace(FileNameZip).CopyHere oApp.Namespace(FolderName).items

        'Keep script waiting until Compressing is done
        On Error Resume Next
        Do Until oApp.Namespace(FileNameZip).items.Count = _
        oApp.Namespace(FolderName).items.Count
            Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
        Loop
        On Error GoTo 0

        MsgBox "You find the zipfile here: " & FileNameZip

    End If
End Sub
Sub NewZip(sPath)
'Create empty Zip File
'Changed by keepITcool Dec-12-2005
    If Len(Dir(sPath)) > 0 Then Kill sPath
    Open sPath For Output As #1
    Print #1, Chr$(80) & Chr$(75) & Chr$(5) & Chr$(6) & String(18, 0)
    Close #1
End Sub


Function bIsBookOpen(ByRef szBookName As String) As Boolean
' Rob Bovey
    On Error Resume Next
    bIsBookOpen = Not (Application.Workbooks(szBookName) Is Nothing)
End Function


Function Split97(sStr As Variant, sdelim As String) As Variant
'Tom Ogilvy
    Split97 = Evaluate("{""" & _
                       Application.Substitute(sStr, sdelim, """,""") & """}")
End Function
```

https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s7/win001.htm